# Adding multiple elements to dictionary inside the list and appending the dictionary every time and element is added

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
brand = [1,2,3]
```

consider this is the list I want to add to the list of dictionaries below

```
r = [{'time':1,
     'id':1
     'region':[{brand:1}]}]
```

and every time I add the element I want the dictionary to create new dictionary within the list Exampel:

```
r = [{'time':1,
     'id':1
     'region':[{brand:1},
    {'time':1,
     'id':1
     'region':[{brand:2}]
     {'time':1,
     'id':1
     'region':[{brand:3}]}
```

I am new to python and not able to figure out how to do it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
l = [1,2,3]
r = []
for i in l:
  new_dict = {'time':1, 'id':1, 'region':[{"brand":i}]}
  r.append(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'region': [{'brand': 1}], 'time': 1},
 {'id': 1, 'region': [{'brand': 2}], 'time': 1},
 {'id': 1, 'region': [{'brand': 3}], 'time': 1}]
```

**Edit** To address you question in the comment: bear in mind that this will always work in as much as `brand` and `time` are of the same length.

```
brand = [1,2,3]
time = [1,2,3]
r = []
for i in range(len(l)):
  new_dict = {'time':time[i], 'id':1, 'region':[{"brand":brand[i]}]}
  r.append(new_dict)
```

Comment: That did work Thanks. What if i have multiple lists like: brand = [1,2,3], time=[1,2,3] and need the update like [{'id': 1, 'region': [{'brand': 1}], 'time': 1},
 {'id': 1, 'region': [{'brand': 2}], 'time': 2},
 {'id': 1, 'region': [{'brand': 3}], 'time': 3}]

Comment: If brand and time are the same you can do: [{'time':1, 'id':1, 'region':[{"brand":i}], 'time': i} for i in range(1, 3)]

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your question

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
brand = [1,2,3]
r = list()
for i in brand:
    r.append(dict(time=1, id=1, region=[dict(brand=i)]))
```

Output:

```
[{'time': 1, 'id': 1, 'region': [{'brand': 1}]},
{'time': 1, 'id': 1, 'region': [{'brand': 2}]},
{'time': 1, 'id': 1, 'region': [{'brand': 3}]}]
```

And if you want you can set the values of 'time' and 'id' just like 'region':

```
brand = [1,2,3]
r = list()
for i in brand:
    r.append(dict(time=i, id=i, region=[dict(brand=i)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like that:

```
brand = [1, 2, 3]
r = [{'time': 1, 'id': 1, 'region':[{"brand": i}]} for i in brand]
```